# Get values of each row

Tags: php, mysql

In my mysql tables I have for example a row that holds values, lets call this table "days" and the row "haircuts".

So I have 5 rows all with "1","2","3","4","5" under "haircuts". What I want to do, in php, is add them all together and echo. So it would maybe look like this:

```
echo "Total haircuts: ",$haircuts;
```

Which would hopefully show:

```
Total haircuts: 15
```

I can't figure out how, though. Here's how I'm currently doing it.

```
$getstats = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM stats");
$gotstats = mysqli_fetch_array($getstats);
$haircuts = $gotstats['haircuts'];
```

But it only echoes the "haircuts" of the first row? :(

I have multiple columns I would like to total and echo too if that is possible?

Comment: Just use `sum()` -- `select sum(haircuts) total...`

Comment: and add error checking to your `mysqli_...()` calls ...

Comment: days, haircuts - I'm lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should use MySQL SUM().

```
SELECT SUM(haircuts) as tot_cuts FROM stats;

$gotstats['tot_cuts'];
```

Comment: Sum works, thanks! (can only mark as right answer in 9 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MySQL statment `SUM` in your query, just change your code by this one:

```
$getstats = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(haircuts) AS totalhaircuts FROM stats");
$gotstats = mysqli_fetch_array($getstats);
$totalhaircuts = $gotstats['totalhaircuts'];
echo "Total haircuts: ",$totalhaircuts;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use loop for getting all rows. Example:

```
$getstats = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM stats");
while($gotstats = mysqli_fetch_array($getstats)){
    $haircuts = $gotstats['haircuts']; 
    echo $haircuts . '<br />';
}
```